# Symfony Listener gone missing after minor changes in Controller

Tags: php, symfony, listener, lexikjwtauthbundle

I am encountering some weir behaviour with Symfony listener. I have a working configuration, but when I change or add something to the controller, `Expected to find class "App\EventListener\AuthenticationSuccessListener"` shows up. The change could be only something inside route path string. All code is [here](https://github.com/pajasry/NinersXWeb/tree/login_extension).
Remove cache and server restart doesn't help.

Listener

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Event\AuthenticationSuccessEvent;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Event\AuthenticationFailureEvent;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Response\JWTAuthenticationFailureResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;

class AuthenticationListener
{
    /**
     * @var SerializerInterface
     */
    private $serializer;

    public function __construct(SerializerInterface $serializer)
    {
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
    }

    /**
     * @param AuthenticationSuccessEvent $event
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccessResponse(AuthenticationSuccessEvent $event)
    {

        $event->setData([
            'user' => $this->serializer->normalize($event->getUser(), null, ['groups' => ['basic']]),
            'token' => $event->getData()['token'],
        ]);

    }

}
```

services.yaml

```
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:

services:
    app.event.authentication_success_response:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\AuthenticationListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: lexik_jwt_authentication.on_authentication_success, method: onAuthenticationSuccessResponse }
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\IsGranted;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;

class ApiUserController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/api/verify_token", methods="POST", name="api_verify_token")
     * @IsGranted("ROLE_USER")
     */
    public function verifyToken(User $user = null){
        return new JsonResponse([], 200);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think it's a namespace/psr-4 issue. the namespace of the listener should be App\EventListener not AppBundle\EventListener (both the .php file as well as services.yaml)., alternatively you should explicitly add AppBundle\EventListener to your composer.json (which I would definitely NOT prefer)

Comment: Thank you very much. It help me a lot.

Comment: Please share the full and exact error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by @Jakumi answer. The error was caused by `namespace AppBundle\EventListener`. After the change to `App\EventListener` error disappear.